# How to read a limited lines in my file as the python is giving a Memory error

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON data of about 7GB size, and I want to read just a few lines of that data(NOT ALL THE DATA). When I print all of the data there is a memory error.

I tried to print it using pandas and numpy but I couldn't print it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_json("xyz.json")

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Maybe check out the `chunksize` and `lines` option of `pandas` `read_json` see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If file consists of huge number of small objects separated by newline, then read file line by line and parse each object individually:

```
import json
import itertools

f = open("abc.json")
for line in itertools.islice(f,3):
  line = line.strip()
  if not line: continue
  print(json.loads(line))

f.close();
```

Will read only 3 first objects from `abc.json`

Comment: Thank you sir. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read in a chunk of the data with chunksize

Answer (score 0):

[The panda documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-jsonl) details how to read a large input line by line. You can make the `read_json` method return an iterator which will read and return on fragment of the file at a time:

```
df = pd.read_json("xyz.json", lines=True, chunksize=1)
for chunk in df:
   print(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a json reader, which treats input file as a stream (not reading it whole, but as needed).

```
import ijson
from itertools import islice
f = open('xyz.json','r')
elements = ijson.items(f,'')
for x in islice(elements,3):
  print(x)
```

Will print first 3 objects from json.

Install using (linux)

```
sudo apt install python3-ijson
```

or pip. See ijson: https://pypi.org/project/ijson/

Comment: in for loop I can only print the first object and when I change it to 2 or 3 there is an error which is:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hi.py", line 5, in <module>
    for x in islice(elements,2):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ijson/common.py", line 138, in items
    current, event, value = next(prefixed_events)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ijson/common.py", line 65, in parse
    for event, value in basic_events:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ijson/backends/python.py", line 192, in basic_parse
    raise common.JSONError('Additional data')
ijson.common.JSONError: Additional data

Comment: This error means that your file is not a valid JSON. Probably it consists of more than one JSON object: like two objects {...}{...} instead of array of two objects [{...},{...}], or similar problem.

Comment: @NajimSadat if you have a file in this format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON you need to find delimiter first, and pass a file-like object which stops at first delimiter (e.g. '\n')

Comment: Is there any solution for it? I mean how to print more than one object?

Comment: It depends on how large are the objects, and if delimiter is a newline or something else. If each object is small, and objects are separated by newline, do just open, read line by line, and use standard json package.